# None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements:.... in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, provisioning-profile

I have been facing the issue of validating the archive which was working fine with all previous versions of the app builds. Now I am getting the error as:

No matching provisioning profiles found for "Application/abc.app"
None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements:com.developer.associated-domain, beta-reports-active, aps-environment.

I tried all possible ways that exist in Stack Overflow. It means new profiles, certificates, reinstalling new OS, reinstalling Xcode, Cleaning, deleting derived data, code signing editing, exporting the certificate etc..... Still I get the same error.

Comment: is Issue in Entitlements? `Capabilities` section

Comment: Entitlement File                                             Dictionary    2 items
aps-environment                                           String    development
com.apple.developer.associated-domains    Array

This is my entitlement.

Comment: Just go to your developer account `identifier` -> edit and in name just prefix `XC com` and check

Comment: its already XC com. I have marked In-app purchase, Game center, Associated Domains and APNS in the identifier.

Comment: For which functionality you are using Entitlements, Shared Extension?

Comment: I used it for deep linking.

Comment: have you created `Provision Profile` for that target?

Comment: Yes I have made the provision Profile. And this used to work since last 18 releases and I used to upload from 2 different mac machines. But now its throwing this error.

Comment: Thanks all and @PiyushRathi It has been resolved. I dint have the practice of checking the project info and entitlements with the Provision profile data for matching the info. aps-environment in entitlement was development whereas in PP it was production. I changed the aps-environment in entitlement manually to production. and it got uploaded.

Comment: Cool... Happy Coading :)